# Slow Query Execution: Takes long time to execute => Very Strange Why?

Tags: sql, sql-server, performance, t-sql

I am using SQL Server 2012 Express from Microsoft. Database/data size is small to intermediate with only like 50 tables, although some tables do have 100k - 200k records. The query that gives me trouble does run across one of the larger tables (time_list).

Tables involved:

- time_list (~200k records)
- Code_Department_Types (20 records)
- Code_Billing_Types (50 records)
- Job_Info (~65k records)
- Job_Address (~83k records)
- Job_Plans (~75k records)
- Companies (~5k records)

BAD NEWs: The current tables do not have any indexes besides PK/FK

PROBLEM:

I have a query (see below) that runs very slow and the execution speed depends on the date filter applied to the query, but the reason why it runs slow is counter intuitive.

Observations based on my test cases below:

1. It appears that once I try to query anything within the year 2019, it just kills the performance.
2. It is interesting to note that I can query huge date ranges and everything runs fine, but a very specific range in year 2019 causes the query just to stall.
   I even ran the query by removing the date filter completely and it executed in  681 ms.
3. This problem is observable on LIVE server and test server and is reproducible by playing with the date filter in the query. Both servers observe very similar time delays although hardware is a bit different.

   Let me present the test cases (date filter is applied at the bottom of the query):

   - Case 1) Execution time: 681 ms <= LIGHTNING FAST

   No date filter, the query returns the most records in the result set.

   - Case 2) Execution time: 1.1 sec <= FAST!

   Date filter range: and t.date between '1900-01-01' AND '2019-03-31'

   Time Range: ~119 years

   - Case 3) Execution time: 1:40 min(s) <= SLOW

   Date filter range: and t.date between '2019-01-01' and '2019-03-06'

   Time Range: ~ 3 months

   - Case 4) Execution time: Had to stop the query after 6 min(s), it just kept going <= SUPER SLOW

   Date filter range: and t.date between '2018-03-01' AND '2019-03-31'

   Time Range: ~1 year

Actual Query:

```
select 
    result.JobId as ProjectId, job.file_number as FileNumber, 
    job.street_name1 as ProjectAddress, addr.StreetMetadata as AddressMetadata, 
    client.client_number as ClientNumber, 
    pln.Lot as PlanLot, pln.plan_number as PlanNumber,
    result.TimeDate as TimeDate
from
    (select distinct
         job.entity_id as JobId, job.client_entity_id as ClientId, 
         (select top 1 t2.date 
          from time_list t2
          inner join Code_Department_Types dept2 on dept2.entity_id = t2.department_id
          inner join Code_Billing_Types bill2 on bill2.entity_id = t2.billing_id
          where (t2.job_id = job.entity_id and ((bill2.name='L/O on GRADE' and dept2.name='F')))
          order by t2.date desc) as TimeDate
    from 
        time_list t
    inner join 
        Code_Department_Types dept on dept.entity_id = t.department_id
    inner join 
        Code_Billing_Types bill on bill.entity_id = t.billing_id
    inner join 
        Job_Info job on t.job_id = job.entity_id
    where 
         EXISTS (select t.entity_id FROM time_list t1
                inner join Code_Department_Types dept on dept.entity_id = t1.department_id
                inner join Code_Billing_Types bill on bill.entity_id = t1.billing_id
                where 
                    t1.job_id = job.entity_id and (bill.name='L/O on GRADE' and dept.name='F')
        ) and not 
         EXISTS (select t.entity_id FROM time_list t1
                inner join Code_Department_Types dept on dept.entity_id = t1.department_id
                inner join Code_Billing_Types bill on bill.entity_id = t1.billing_id
                where 
                    t1.job_id = job.entity_id and (bill.name='SRPR' and dept.name='F')
        )
            and t.date between '1900-01-01' AND '2019-03-31' -- FAST! (1.1 sec)
            --and t.date between '2019-01-01' and '2019-03-06'  -- SLOW (1:40)
                --and t.date between '2018-03-01' AND '2019-03-31'  -- SLOW (> 6 mins, and still going, had to stop it)
        ) as result

        inner join Companies client on client.entity_id = result.ClientId
        inner join Job_Info job on job.entity_id = result.JobId
        inner join Job_Address addr on addr.JobId = job.entity_id
        inner join Job_Plans pln on pln.job_id = result.JobId
        order by FileNumber asc;
```

Comment: What indexes do you have on your table, and how recently have you updated the statistics? Could you [Paste the Plan](https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/)?

Comment: I have updated my description listing tables and number of records they each contain. To answer your question: These tables have only PK/FK,- there are no other indexes on other columns. What software can I use to get the SQL Plan?

Comment: That's all covered in the instructions, @ActiveX, however, there's your problem *"there are no other indexes on other columns"*.

Comment: Slight detour...but an important one...https://sqlblog.org/2011/10/19/what-do-between-and-the-devil-have-in-common

Comment: @Larnu Yes, clearly that's bad - no indexes; But the behavior is still strange, you think it is purely index related? Anyway, I will try and put indexes on the fields that are in the where clause, specifically the date.

Comment: SQL Server stores data in heaps. If you have a Clustered Index, then the data is (kinda) ordered in the order of that Clustered Index. When, however, you write a query that asks for rows "between these dates", the Clustered Index alone is useless (unless it's on your date column). It's kind of like asking someone to bring you a list of all the people called "John" in the phone book. All the names are alphabetically sorted by surname, not firstname, so the only way you can get that data is checking every entry. That is exactly what your SQL Server has to end up doing here.

Comment: Actually, it's probably not. Due to a clause like `'1900-01-01' AND '2019-03-31'` the server is very likely coming to the conclusion "this is going to be everything"; probably due to a previous query or some statistics. Thus it doesn't check the values, it just throws the phone book at you. On the other hand, for the latter clause `BETWEEN '2018-03-01' AND '2019-03-31'` it knows that's only a few rows; so off it goes, diligently checking **every** row (which according to your post is over 200,000 rows, so will take a little while; especially as Express is limited to a single sock or 4 cores).

Comment: you may be encountering the [ascending date problem](https://sqlinthewild.co.za/index.php/2011/03/22/statistics-row-estimations-and-the-ascending-date-column/) - where the most recent dates are not represented in the stats and a bad plan ensues

Comment: Okay, I analyzed the query to see which fields needed indexing. In this case, it was just the date field. After I put the index on the time_list.date field problem disappeared. Thanks!!!

Comment: creating an index will have created new stats on the column so the index itself may or may not have helped

Comment: Okay, so how do I test if the problem is gone? Restart SQL Server instance to clear everything?

Comment: If you didn't collect the execution plan when the problem was occurring you're out of luck. Restarting SQL Server isn't going to help. If the problem recurs at some later stage with the index in place consider the ascending date issue and that you might need to schedule more frequent updates of stats on that column

Comment: @MartinSmith "consider the ascending date issue and that you might need to schedule more frequent updates of stats on that column " <= can you explain what you mean by this?

Comment: see the link above

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As pointed out by the posts, adding an index (on the date field) immediately fix the problem. I will monitor this but for now marking this post as "Answered".

Answer (score 0):

Your comment specifying run time deltas on updating your date parameters suggests there's some data integrity issues. Does this help at all?

`CAST(t.[Date] AS DATE) BETWEEN '1900-01-01' AND '2019-03-31'`

Comment: Actually, root cause of the problem was no index on the date field!

Comment: Glad to hear a fix was identified. Best of luck implementing!